# Subtraction of list and elements of matrix Python

Tags: python, list, numpy, matrix

Im new in Python and have a question about numpy.
There is a matrix:

```
 x = np.arange(-1,1.1,0.7)
 y = np.arange(-1,1.1,0.7)
 X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

#Result for X

  [[-1.  -0.3  0.4  1.1]
   [-1.  -0.3  0.4  1.1]
   [-1.  -0.3  0.4  1.1]
   [-1.  -0.3  0.4  1.1]]
```

and a list:

```
RX = [0, 0.1, 0.2]
```

How i can subtract RX list from every element of X?

```
#result array

[[[-1. , -1.1, -1.2]
 [-0.3, -0.4, -0.5]
 [ 0.4,  0.3,  0.2]
 [ 1.1,  1. ,  0.9]]

 [[-1. , -1.1, -1.2]
 [-0.3, -0.4, -0.5]
 [ 0.4,  0.3,  0.2]
 [ 1.1,  1. ,  0.9]]

 [[-1. , -1.1, -1.2]
  [-0.3, -0.4, -0.5]
  [ 0.4,  0.3,  0.2]
  [ 1.1,  1. ,  0.9]]

 [[-1. , -1.1, -1.2]
  [-0.3, -0.4, -0.5]
  [ 0.4,  0.3,  0.2]
  [ 1.1,  1. ,  0.9]]]
```

and sum  matrices (make a rows from result_array matrices).

```
[[-3.2 , -1.2, 0.9, 3]
[-3.2 , -1.2, 0.9, 3]
[-3.2 , -1.2, 0.9, 3]
[-3.2 , -1.2, 0.9, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by

```
newvals = np.array([[val - np.array(A) for val in line] for line in X])
```

Comment: Better yet - use broadcasting: `X[:,:,None]-np.array(RX)`